# Scheduling, without schedule library

Tags: python

I need to schedule a simple task to be done everytime this script runs so for this i have some problems.

I am working on a software that i don't own, and don't have all python libraries, so i am trying to get a workarround to my schedule problem.
This script will run when the program is online (the program can crash so i will need some way to track the exact time, can't be a wait x time)

So what i want my script to do its, every time the computer clocks hit "X" time then print ("Log out time") and every time the computer hit "Y" time then print ("Log in time")

So i will set my vars first to this time be editable, and this script will run and close on does times, so he will have to import the time every time he opens.

Ive tried to do some time in seconds to try to "create a time to operate" but  time.time() gets time sinse epoc, i had no luck with this.

Also i had an idea to do INT number calculations like its 10 - current time, but i can't find a way to make current time an int number.

This is what i am looking to do but i can't use schedule.

```
`def work():
print("Study and work hard")​

# Every day at 12am or 00:00 time work() is called.
schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(work)`
```

Comment: So, what exactly can and can't you do in your apparently special Python environment?

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: I have time and datetime....

Comment: The hole code? thats a small part of the code.
And i don't have nothing done on that part so far, all i tried failed

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution

```
Import time
if time.localtime().tm_hour == 14 and time.localtime().tm_min == 33:
    print('its 14:33')
    time.sleep(60)
if time.localtime().tm_hour == 12 and time.localtime().tm_min == 0:
    print('twelve o clock')
    time.sleep(60)
```